# Retrieving data like movie title/details/screening time from a cinema website to android app

Tags: android

I can access the cinema website's html. I need info of the movie like, movie title, duration and screening time. How can I retrieve these data and use them in android app?

Here are the info from the site's HTML:

```
<a href="/movies/movie/300-rise-of-an-empire" class="movie-title">300: Rise Of An 
Empire</a>
<br>R-16
<br>1 hr. 40 mins
<div>
<span class="show-times">09:00pm</span>
</div>
```

How can I use these info for android app?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to look for json or xml data instead of parsing the HTML data, Or you can check the android web view control to present the HTML data on android

Android Web view Reference:
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html